# False iteration over list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, iteration

I have a function that's suppose to minimize the quantity of a letter in a list if a given word contains that letter. That's the def of the function:

```
word = 'better'
hand = {'b':1, 'r':1, 's':3, 't':2, 'z':1, 'e':3}
def updateHand(hand, word):
    handCopy = hand.copy()
    for x in word:
        print(x)
        print(hand)
        handCopy[x] = hand.get(x,0) - 1
        print(handCopy)
    return handCopy
```

And that's the Output:

```
b
{'s': 3, 'b': 1, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
e
{'s': 3, 'b': 1, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 2}
t
{'s': 3, 'b': 1, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'z': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 2}
t
{'s': 3, 'b': 1, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'z': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 2}
e
{'s': 3, 'b': 1, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'z': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 1, 'e': 2}
r
{'s': 3, 'b': 1, 'z': 1, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'e': 3}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'z': 1, 't': 1, 'r': 0, 'e': 2}
Out[110]: {'b': 0, 'e': 2, 'r': 0, 's': 3, 't': 1, 'z': 1}
```

Why is my function skipping the second `t` and / or doesn't eliminate it from the list? Thanks!

Comment: `handCopy[x] = hand.get(x,0) - 1` - consider this line carefully.

Comment: Also, that's not a list.

Comment: Because `hand.get('t')` is `2`.

Comment: @melpomene so if `x in word` hits the second `t` it should go  down to `0`, or?

Comment: `handCopy[x] -= 1`

Comment: You're fetching the initial value from `hand`, which never changes.

Comment: I don't see any lists.

Comment: @BrendanAbel thanks a lot! That was it! Can you tell me why it didn't do the same with my code since I iterate over the same letter again!?

Comment: It sounds like you really want to be using a `Counter` from the `collections` module in the standard library. If `hand` was a `Counter` already, your whole function body could become `return hand.subtract(word)` (you might also need to do a `copy()` first). If you don't need to keep track of negative or zero counts, you could instead use `hand - Counter(word)` which does a copy automatically.

Comment: @MickeyMahoney solution what gave you BrendanAbel is not good if you don't have key ``x`` in your ``handCopy`` dict. It will raise KeyError exception. Take a look at my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39925817/false-iteration-over-list/39926144#39926144

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider this situation:

```
hand = {'b':1, 'r':1, 's':3, 't':2, 'z':1, 'e':3}
```

so we have hand as a dict. Now we do this one:

```
x = hand.get('t',0) - 1
print x
```

result will be 1. Let's do it again:

```
x = hand.get('t',0) - 1
print x
```

again 1. Why? Because you're not updating value for `'t'` key in hand dict. So it's the same situation as in your code:

```
handCopy[x] = hand.get(x,0) - 1
```

so you should do it in this way:

```
handCopy[x] = handCopy.get(x, 0) - 1
```

**Solution**

```
word = 'better'
hand = {'b':1, 'r':1, 's':3, 't':2, 'z':1, 'e':3}
def updateHand(hand, word):
    handCopy = hand.copy()
    for x in word:         
        print(x)           
        print(hand)        
        handCopy[x] = handCopy.get(x,0) - 1
        print(handCopy)    
    return handCopy
```

result:

```
b
{'b': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 3, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'z': 1}
e
{'b': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 2, 't': 2, 'r': 1, 'z': 1}
t
{'b': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 2, 't': 1, 'r': 1, 'z': 1}
t
{'b': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 2, 't': 0, 'r': 1, 'z': 1}
e
{'b': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 1, 't': 0, 'r': 1, 'z': 1}
r
{'b': 1, 'e': 3, 's': 3, 'r': 1, 't': 2, 'z': 1}
{'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 1, 't': 0, 'r': 0, 'z': 1}
Out[110]: {'s': 3, 'b': 0, 'e': 1, 't': 0, 'r': 0, 'z': 1}
```

Comment: What a stupid mistake to make. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MickeyMahoney sure, no problem. We all make mistakes.